# Need help understanding the behavior of event loop in this code

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events, event-loop

Take a look at the following Javascript code:

```
var content = document.body

function pausecomp(millis)
{
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < millis);
}

setTimeout(function () {
  content.innerText = "callback called"
}, 2000)

content.innerText = "timeout set"

setTimeout(function () {
  content.innerText = "one second passed, sleeping for 4 more seconds"
  pausecomp(4000)
}, 1000)
```

I was expecting the following output to be displayed on the page:

1. "timeout set"
2. One second passes
3. "one second passed, sleeping for 4 more seconds"
4. 4 more seconds pass
5. "callback called"

Since the second callback will be queued before the first one, and it will block the stack for 4 more seconds

Instead I see the following output:

1. "timeout set"
2. 5 seconds pass
3. "callback called"

What's the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: Using a long blocking while loop is a horrible practice. Use a promise with a setTimeout to resolve it for non blocking delay

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you're seeing is the result of single-threaded synchronous execution blocking DOM rendering.

Here's what happens:

1. `innerText` set to `timeout set`.
2. The second `setTimeout` fires after 1 second.
3. `innerText` is set to `one second passed, sleeping for 4 more seconds`, but the browser does not re-render the DOM until the execution thread is released.
4. `pausecomp` holds the thread for 4 seconds, synchronously.
5. `pausecomp` finishes and the first `setTimeout` immediately executes because at this point it has already been queued up.
6. `innerText` is set to `callback called`.
7. Browser is finally able to re-render the page (5 seconds elapsed) and displays `callback called`.

Comment: "*the browser cannot re-render the DOM until the execution thread is released*" - the browser *can* do it (some older engines actually did), but it usually chooses not to.

Comment: @Bergi Changed `cannot` to `does not`.